# Function to wrap function and provide one property of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a new function from an initial function, with the initial function taking a single object argument and the new function taking the same single object argument apart from populated fields. I've got something like this so far:

```
function returnNewFunc<TArg extends { b?: string }>(
  initialFunc: (arg: TArg) => void
) {
  const newFunc = (arg: Omit<TArg, "b">) =>
    initialFunc({ ...arg, b: "hello" });

  return newFunc
}

const funcA = ({ b, c }: { b: string; c: string }) => {
  console.log(b, c);
};
const funcB = returnNewFunc(funcA)
funcB({c: "test"}) // funcB should have 'c' as the only field in its argument
```

The issue here is I get a `could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint` typescript error, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: This is called partial application.

Comment: What you've described is, as @Bergi said, partial application, but your code seems to be doing something else: accepting just a single argument of an object type and augmenting that object with a `b` property. Which do you want?

Comment: The error means that `newFunc<{b: "goodbye"}>(…)` would have to fail - the type `{b: "goodbye"}` does extend `{b?: string}`, but passing `{b: "hello"}` to a function expecting `{b: "goodbye"}` is wrong.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want what my code is trying to do. I thought my description was more or less equivalent, but happy to be corrected.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Call it "partial application of named arguments" :-)

Comment: Could you fix whatever's going on with `returnNewFunc(a)` and `b({c})`? Are they typos?  The code should be a [mre] without extraneous errors.

Comment: @jcalz It was like that initially but I changed it pretty promptly - maybe StackOverflow being down somehow showed you a previous version.

Comment: Hmm, okay, weird.  Anyway your version isn't type safe, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRGZEN).  You can fix it to be type safe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8Ep0N), but it's not nice to use because the compiler can't infer `T` properly.  If I were trying to do this so that callers got ergonomic behavior I'd write [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NlEPOm).  I could write these up as an answer if it addresses your question fully.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow, that's a helluva complicated overload!

Comment: @Bergi yeah .  I really had to fight against the TS inference heuristics.  Given a callback of type `(props: Omit<T, "b"> & {b?: string}) => void` the compiler is essentially unable to infer `T`.  Instead I have to give it a callback of generic type `F` and then compute `T` from it.  And `F` can't even be constrained directly via `<F extends XXX>`.  It's a mess.

Comment: @jcalz wow, thanks. I did not expect it to be this complicated. I think it's good so, please, by all means write it up as an answer and I'll accept.